# sending echo and error to both terminal and file log

Tags: bash, shell, unix, logging, terminal

I am trying to modify a script someone created for unix in shell. This script is mostly used to run on backed servers with no human interaction, however I needed to make another script to allow users to input information. So, it is just modifying to old version for user input. But the biggest issue I am running into is trying to get both error logs and echos to be saved in a log file. The script has a lot of them, but I wanted to have those shown on the terminal as well as send them to the log file specified, to be looked into later.

What I have is this:

```
exec 1> ${LOG} 2>&1
```

This line is pretty much send everything to the log file. That is all good, but I also have people trying to enter in information in the script, and it is sending everything to the log file including the echo needed for the prompt. This line is also at the beginning of the script, but reading more into the stderr and stdout messages. I tried:

```
exec 2>&1 1>>${LOG}
exec 1 | tee ${LOG} But only getting error when running it this "./bash_pam.sh: line 39: exec: 1: not found"
```

I have went over site [such as this](http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2014/09/09/redirecting-bash-script-output-to-syslog/) to solve the issue, but I am not understanding why it does not print to both. The way I insert it, it either only sends it to the log location and not to the terminal, or it sends it to the terminal, but nothing is persevered in the log.

EDIT: Some of the solutions, for this have mentioned that certain fixes will work in bash, but not in /bin/sh.

Comment: If I understand correctly you only want errors to be shown in stdout and logged to a file?

Comment: Well, I wanted the echos to come to the terminal, but at the same time, wanted the echos and errors sent to the log location.

Comment: By "echos" you mean no error output, that's what is unclear.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion, modifying scripts, let alone trying to create one is not my forte.

Comment: `command 2>&1 | tee -a out.log` will output (errors and regular messages) to screen and a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like all output to be printed onto the console, while also being printed to a `logfile.txt` you would run this command on your script:

```
bash your_script.sh 2>&1 | tee -a logfile.txt
```

Or calling it within the file:

```
<bash_command> 2>&1 | tee -a logfile.txt
```

To append to `logfile.txt` instead of overwriting, add the `-a` option to `tee`.

Comment: This will overwrite `logfile.txt` for every new line printed on terminal. You need `tee -a` to append new lines to logfile.